# Make a drawable in Android created programmatically fits parent's width and has proportional height

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

So I am loading images from URLs with this method

```
public Drawable loadImage(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage()+" oh noo ");
        return null;
    }
}
```

But I want the image's width to be the same as its parent (that is the root element with height and width 100%). I couldn't find a way to do it using only XML. It always leaves paddings on the edges. And I found out it is because the image doesn't have the same ratio of the screen. screen is, for example 16:9 and image is 4:3. Android will make paddings to fill this difference.

**Do you know how can I do it programmatically when I load the image? And I need this image to remain as big as the screen's width even when the device rotates (so I think I will need to calculate it gain)**

I am using this code to get the size of the screen

```
public Size getScreenSize(){
    Size screenSize = new Size();

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    screenSize.height = metrics.heightPixels;
    screenSize.width = metrics.widthPixels;

    return screenSize;
}

public class Size{
    public double height;
    public double width;
}
```

@EDIT1

This is how I insert the drawable in the View. The view is already declared in the activity's XML

```
ImageView picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture);

picture.setImageDrawable(loadImage(url));
```

@EDIT2

this is how I wrote the activity layout and its style

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <!-- style="@style/globalHeader" -->
    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/globalHeader"  
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"        
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="#f00"
        >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the appearance I want to achieve

https://docs.google.com/a/uniriotec.br/file/d/0B2abPynX9PhkODhRVEkwcUphY28/edit?pli=1

Comment: Are you setting the `Drawable` to an `ImageView`?

Comment: If you want to set downloaded drawable in ImageView, you can use AQuery instead of this above method. Post your code where you set this drawable?

Comment: @BrijeshPatel Ok, I'm editing my original post with the code where I set the drawable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think so this is the one you are finding for.
just rescale the image of drawable taken from internet.

```
Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext()
                .getResources(), drawable);
        if (bit != null) {
            Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bit, width,
                    height, true);
            imageView.setBitmap(resizedBitmap);
            }
```

the width and height are calculated below

```
    DisplayMetrics disp = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(disp);

    int width = disp.widthPixels;
    int height = disp.heightPixels;
```

@EDIT

```
private Bitmap loadImage(String URL)
{        

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;        
    try {
        in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;                
}
private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString)
        throws IOException
        {
            InputStream in = null;
            int response = -1;

            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))                    
                throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

            try{
                HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConn.connect();

                response = httpConn.getResponseCode();                
                if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) 
                {
                    in = httpConn.getInputStream();                                
                }                    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new IOException("Error connecting");            
            }
            return in;    
}
```

Directly take the bitmap image and rescale it and use it.

Comment: what is the variable `drawable` passed to `decodeResource` ? Will the image still fitting 100% of the width screen when the mobile rotates?

Comment: ya because the width changes according to the screen orientation

Comment: drawable is the image taken from the internet in your program

Comment: it is giving me an error. It says the method is not applicable for the arguments. It is not expecting to receive a drawable as the second argument. it says it wants an ID

Comment: Hey Sridhat, it generated the following result

https://docs.google.com/a/uniriotec.br/file/d/0B2abPynX9PhkTlFXNktmdTd2TW8/edit?pli=1

now I have the paddings around the drawable as I mentioned in my original message. it seems to happen when the screen is larger than the image ratio

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how will it behave with device rotation, but I believe you actually can do it from your xml layout, setting your [ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) to `CENTER_CROP` should do the trick.-

> CENTER_CROP : Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Comment: so when I add `scaleType` it seems that the ImageView is expanding to fill the remaining space in the screen, and it creates a big padding over and below the drawable making it distant from the surrounding elements

Comment: Mmh any screenshot? Could you add a background color to `ImageView` like (android:background="@color/red") just to make sure that padding comes from the image?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/a/uniriotec.br/file/d/0B2abPynX9PhkTlFXNktmdTd2TW8/edit?pli=1

yes, this is what I did in my project. I added a red background to the imageview and it leaves paddings around the image (this is not what I did in the example in the link, where the image is shown in red and paddings in white)

Comment: Would be useful a look to the complete layout.xml, but my guess is that the padding is related to the layout "on top" of the image, not the image itself.

Comment: I am sorry, I gave you the wrong feedback. That was the appearance before the `scaleType`, with only `adjustViewBounds`. this is how it looks like after `scaleType`

https://docs.google.com/a/uniriotec.br/file/d/0B2abPynX9PhkRml6NWlvSHI2bm8/edit?pli=1

Comment: And that black border is supposed to be the edge of the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="#f00"
        >
```

Comment: So @Patel, with `android:scaleType="fitXY"` AND adding the following code in my Activity `picture.getLayoutParams().width = screenWidth; picture.getLayoutParams().height = screenHeight;` I could make it work (no paddings)! but when I rotate the device it doesn't fit the screen. do you know how to recalculate it when I rotate the device?

Comment: remove your calcuation.remove this two lines picture.getLayoutParams().width = screenWidth; picture.getLayoutParams().height = screenHeight; and check it once. reply me please.

Comment: there i no need of any calculations. scaletype "fitxy" will set image size as per screen resolution.

Comment: this is what happens https://docs.google.com/a/uniriotec.br/file/d/0B2abPynX9PhkRml6NWlvSHI2bm8/edit?pli=1

the ImageView seems to be filling the remaining space in the screen

Comment: so picture covers screen width. that actually you want , right?

Comment: hmm not exactly. I want the image's width to be equal screen's width. and keep the image's height proportional to its original size after the re-sizing. I will update my original post with what I want to achieve

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38107/discussion-between-brijesh-patel-and-victor-ferreira)

Comment: click on "continue this discussinon in chat"